# text jumps into imagecontainer html bootstrap

Tags: html, layout, bootstrap-4

currently I am playing around with HTML Bootstrap 4 and desingning a litte webpage. After discovering and implementing an collapse button which will show 2 pics on click, I now have a layout problem. the collaps button should only hide and show the two pictures, which it does, but on showing the images, the bottom text will somehow jump in between the pics. Until now I couldn't find the answer I need, so I hope one of you may Help me.

[how it is not supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfCso.png)

And this is my code (please note that I had to remove the correct URL as I have no permission to show it) I use no CSS right now

```html
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#hide" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse">Surprise</a>
        <div id="hide" class="collapse">
            <img align="left" src="https://www.****.jpg"
                data-anim-type="" width="500" height="300">

            <img align="right" src="https://www.****.jpg" alt="***"
                width="500" height="300">
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
<br>
    <div class="container">
        <blockquote class="blockquote" style="-webkit-text-fill-color:whitesmoke">
            <p2 class="lead">*** supportet auch Auszubildende und Praktikanten mit allen Kräften und Mitteln!</p2>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code and after look at output:

```
<div class="container">
<a href="#hide" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse">Surprise</a>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="hide" class="collapse">
            <img align="left" src="http://www.***.jpg"
                    data-anim-type="" width="500" height="300">

            <img align="left" src="http://www.***.jpg"
                    alt="***" width="500" height="300">
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <blockquote class="blockquote">
        <p2 class="lead">*** supportet auch Auszubildende und Praktikanten mit allen Kräften und Mitteln!</p2>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```